# how to destroy stl Queue created on heap?

Tags: c++

As per req i have to create stl queue on heap
i have created stl queue on heap in constructor of my class as per below code

```
queue<int> *myqueue;
myqueue=new queue<int>();
```

Now in destructor i want to destroy it:
so i have written code

```
while(!myqueue->empty())
{
    myqueue->pop();
}
```

please tell me is it right way to destroy it or there is any other mean to avoid memory leak .Please note that
delete myqueue is giving segmentation fault.

Comment: If your queue is inside a class, it does not make any sense that the queue must be created on the heap. What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All STL containers have a member `clear()` that can be used to erase their content. All STL containers will call this member in their destructor, so you won't have to do it manually. So all you have to do is to ensure that the queue itself is destroyed. for dynamically (with `new`) allocated objects, that's done by invoking `delete`: `delete myqueue;`.

That said: I find it dubious that you would want to create a queue dynamically, instead of making it an ordinary class member:

```
class myclass {
public: 
  // whatever
private: 
  std::queue<int> myqueue_;
};
```

(Note that `std::queue` will always allocate memory for its content dynamically, even if the queue itself is not dynamically allocated.)

If you have to absolutely create the queue dynamically, make sure you're following the [Rule of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29). The crash you describe is what might happen when you copy around classes with dynamically allocated objects that don't have a copy constructor/assignment operator.

Comment: delete myqueue is giving following error
*** glibc detected  corrupted double-linked list: 0x080ba868 ***
i feel this is the error because i am callingdestructor which has already freed. but i have not destroyed any where this queue?
Can any one please suggest how to destroy queue in this case .According to my requirement it is mandate to create queue on heap

Comment: @james: You do exactly as I said: `delete myqueue;`. If that fails at run-time, this means you have done something wrong and invoked _Undefined Behavior_. That's an easy to make mistake when novices are manually fiddling with dynamically allocated objects. Which is exactly why I wrote "I find it dubious that you would want to create a queue dynamically".